# Delete files and folder with exceptions

Tags: command-line, delete

Problem: I need to delete files and folder from a directory full of files and folders with exceptions of files that I don't want to be deleted.

First attempt:

```
rm -r !(c_50.tbl sim.sh pam.prp PROINT spy.inp s.bak sr.ccmg sr.drp s.echo s.mdl st.prob SUB.bsub ufile)
```

Unfortunately, this command delete everything inside the directory

Note: In brackets the files that I don't want delete. `ufile` is a folder.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Inside `!()` you want to separate patterns (i.e. filenames) with `|` not space. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching and read about "pattern-list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing vertical line "|" (or pipe symbol, vbar, stick, etc.) in between the files listed in the parenthesis.

The command should be:

```
rm -r !(c_50.tbl|sim.sh|pam.prp|PROINT|spy.inp|s.bak|sr.ccmg|sr.drp|s.echo|s.mdl|st.prob|SUB.bsub|ufile)
```

What this command does will remove all the files and sub-directories in the current directory except for `c_50.tbl` or `sim.sh` or `pam.prp` etc.

Comment: Before the command I had to activate: shopt -s extglob